# How to go from list of words to a list of distinct letters in Python

Tags: python, filter, distinct, list-comprehension, letters

Using Python, I'm trying to convert a sentence of words into a flat list of all distinct letters in that sentence.

Here's my current code:

```
words = 'She sells seashells by the seashore'

ltr = []

# Convert the string that is "words" to a list of its component words
word_list = [x.strip().lower() for x in words.split(' ')]

# Now convert the list of component words to a distinct list of
# all letters encountered.
for word in word_list:
    for c in word:
        if c not in ltr:
            ltr.append(c)

print ltr
```

This code returns `['s', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'a', 'b', 'y', 't', 'o', 'r']`, which is correct, but is there a more Pythonic way to this answer, probably using list comprehensions/`set`?

When I try to combine list-comprehension nesting and filtering, I get lists of lists instead of a flat list.

The order of the distinct letters in the final list (`ltr`) is not important; what's crucial is that they be unique.

Comment: +1 for a well-worded question and for including your attempt (what a welcome sight!)

Comment: Note that `str.split` defaults to splitting on whitespace, so `.split(' ')` is usually spelled `.split()`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sets provide a simple, efficient solution.

```
words = 'She sells seashells by the seashore'

unique_letters = set(words.lower())
unique_letters.discard(' ') # If there was a space, remove it.
```

Comment: pretty much the same as ephemient, but your answer if formatted nicer.

Comment: @tgray - this was also posted first; ephemient edited his in afterwards (see edit logs).

Comment: @tgray: it's not about formatting, it's about efficiently applying `.lower`!

Comment: I'd make it one line and more general with unique_letters = set(c for c in words.lower() if c.isalpha())

Comment: Just the kind of shorthand answer I was looking for!   Thanks!

Comment: @job: Why though? This solution is cleaner, even if it is 2 lines *and* it doesn't run a comparison on every letter.

Comment: I didn't notice this when I edited my answer, but in any case, Mike's answer is cleaner.  +1

Answer (score 3):

```
set([letter.lower() for letter in words if letter != ' '])
```

**Edit**: I just tried it and found this will also work (maybe this is what SilentGhost was referring to):

```
set(letter.lower() for letter in words if letter != ' ')
```

And if you need to have a list rather than a set, you can

```
list(set(letter.lower() for letter in words if letter != ' '))
```

Comment: you don't list comprehension there

Comment: @Art Metzer: Note that splitting isn't really necessary, since a string is an iterable type.  This is probably why you were getting lists of lists when you didn't want them.

Comment: @SilentGhost: I don't understand your comment, can you clarify?

Comment: @danben:  you can use a generator expression to avoid creating a new list.  Like in Ignacio's answer.

Comment: you're using list comprehension, you don't have to.

Answer (score 3):

Make `ltr` a set and change your loop body a little:

```
ltr = set()

for word in word_list:
    for c in word:
       ltr.add(c)
```

Or using a list comprehension:

```
ltr = set([c for word in word_list for c in word])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> set('She sells seashells by the seashore'.replace(' ', '').lower())
set(['a', 'b', 'e', 'h', 'l', 'o', 's', 'r', 't', 'y'])
>>> set(c.lower() for c in 'She sells seashells by the seashore' if not c.isspace())
set(['a', 'b', 'e', 'h', 'l', 'o', 's', 'r', 't', 'y'])
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> set(chain(*'She sells seashells by the seashore'.lower().split()))
set(['a', 'b', 'e', 'h', 'l', 'o', 's', 'r', 't', 'y'])
```

Answer (score 2):

here are some timings made with py3k:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> def t():                    # mine (see history)
    a = {i.lower() for i in words}
    a.discard(' ')
    return a

>>> timeit.timeit(t)
7.993071812372081
>>> def b():                    # danben
    return set(letter.lower() for letter in words if letter != ' ')

>>> timeit.timeit(b)
9.982847967921138
>>> def c():                    # ephemient in comment
    return {i.lower() for i in words if i != ' '}

>>> timeit.timeit(c)
8.241267610375516
>>> def d():                    #Mike Graham
    a = set(words.lower())
    a.discard(' ')
    return a

>>> timeit.timeit(d)
2.7693045186082372
```

Comment: @ephemient: it works, but it's a bit slower. and btw, `set(i.lower for i in words if i != ' ')` version is 20% slower in py3k

Answer (score 0):

```
set(l for w in word_list for l in w)
```

Comment: @danben: You *did* notice that `word_list` is already split by spaces, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
words = 'She sells seashells by the seashore'

ltr = list(set(list(words.lower())))
ltr.remove(' ')
print ltr
```

Comment: oh, dear, oh dear, oh dear... here is the useful read: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy